# On prem to Azure IPSec VPN not connecting

Tags: vpn, azure-networking

I have a TP-Link MR6400 router that I am trying to connect to our Azure environment over an IPSec VPN. The trouble is it will never connect.

Settings as follows -

**Azure Connection Settings**

```
Use Azure Private IP Address: Disabled

BGP: Disabled
IPSec /IKE Policy: custom
Phase 1: AES256 SHA1 DHGroup2048
Phase 2: AES256 SHA1 PFS2048
```

**TP-Link IPSec VPN Settings**

```
IPSec connection name: MattHome

Remote IPSec Gateway (URL): 20.26... (public IP of Azure gateway)

Tunnel access from local IP addresses: subnet address

IP Address for VPN: 192.168.1.0
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0

Tunnel access from remote IP addresses: subnet address

IP Address for VPN: 10.1.0.0
Subnet Mask: 255.255.0.0
Key exchange method: AUto (IKE)
Authentication Method: Pre-Shared Key
Pre-Shared Key: abc123
Perfect Forward Secrecy: Enable

==Phase 1==

Mode: Main
Local Identifier Type: Local Wan IP
Remote Identifier Type: Remote Wan IP
Encryption Algorithm: AES - 256
Integrity Algorithm: SHA1
Diffie-Hellman Group for Key Exchange: 2048bit
Key Life Time(Seconds): 3600

==Phase 2==

Encryption Algorithm: AES - 256
Integrity Algorithm: SHA1
Diffie-Hellman Group for Key Exchange: 2048bit
Key Life Time(Seconds):3600
```

**UPDATE**

I have tried to connect a DrayTek (not 4G) to the VPN, in the SysLog I get the error

> [IPSEC][L2L][1:Azure][@0.0.0.0]network error: no route to peer

This to me sounds like a problem in Azure...